# SQL Dynamic Exchange Rate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that provided the exchange rate based on the users selection.

**When I simply type this query, it works fine:**

```
SELECT RATE 

FROM USERCONFIG.dbo.curr 

WHERE CODE = 'GBP'
```

[image]

**However when I try to transfer this into a stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST] (@CCY char(3))

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

EXEC('

SELECT RATE 

FROM USERCONFIG.dbo.curr 

WHERE CODE = ' + @CCY + '
    
    ')
    
END
```

I get the following error message and I can't work out why.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `EXEC ({SQL Code})` syntax here? There's no need.

Comment: If you examine the string that you build, you will immediately see the problem. But there is no need for dynamic sql at all here.

Comment: It's also generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to. But, like I mentioned, there's literally no need for `EXEC ({SQL})` or `sys.sp_executesql` here.

Comment: This is only a small part of the code. Once this is cracked I'm planning to build this out further which will be executed from an Excel front-ended dashboard. So could really just do with some advice on the code rather than the way its being executed.

Comment: Then give us a meaningful example. The above has no reason to use dynamic SQL and so the problem is that you're trying to use it when you shouldn't be.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Larnu, that is a meaningful example. Its the most meaningful it can be, because that's all the code I have. I can't just make something up??? Also thanks for the don't load images comment you took the time to write. It confirms that the image I posted doesn't interfere with any one of the reasons suggest. So good to know I'm not doing anything wrong there.

Comment: Then don't use that code, @Carlos80 . Use the first statement you have without the `EXEC({SQL Statement})`. Use the non-dynamic statement then the problem doesn't exist. The reason for the error is because you are using dynamic SQL, incorrectly, when you don't need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Aside from the design questions (see comments) your dynamic code tries to execute the following query:

```
SELECT RATE 
FROM USERCONFIG.dbo.curr 
WHERE CODE = GBP
```

So it tries to match column CODE to column GBP.
Hence the error.

The way to build dynamic SQL with string conversions is to use single quotes twice around the string like:

```
'SELECT RATE 
 FROM USERCONFIG.dbo.curr 
 WHERE CODE = ''' + @CCY + '''
'
```

The repeated single quotes are turned into a single quote on execution.

Comment: Why inject and not parametrise?

Comment: True, why not write an answer how to approach the parameter conversion so that a beginner can follow and understand? Simply I am at work and try to resolve the issue first. Why not create the real answer yourself instead of writing a comment, Larnu, if you have the time?

Comment: Because the answer is don't use dynamic SQL, and so the OP has their solution; use their original SQL. There is clearly something they aren't telling us and why I have asked them to actually tell us about the *real* problem. I can't answer a question I don't have the information for. My crystal ball isn't that good, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Thank you Knut. I wish other contributors were as helpful. That's all I needed to see, that's solved the problem. Shame I had to put up with all the useless waffle before you saw my question.

Comment: @Carlos80  don't use this solution, it is dangerous. It is wide open to injection. It's not the 1990's any more; SQL injection is a well known, prevalent and completely avoidable vulnerability. It's also one of the biggest contributors to data breaches. yes, your parameter is only a `char(3) here, but if/when it's a larger value, then you're going to give someone malicious a very easy attack vector.

Comment: Correct, what Larnu mentions. Before using dynamic SQL really read up on SQL injection. One tip: On receiving a string truncate anything with and after a semicolon in the string. A parameter shall contain a real value, therefore a semicolon indicates a malicious statement to execute. And this is just one of the myriads of possible attack vectors. As Larnu stated a proper parameterised procedure will work better.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear *why* you are using dynamic SQL here, perhaps you should flesh out your example.

But what you need to do is parameterize it properly, using `sp_executesql`. Do *not* inject it like in the other answer.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST] (@CCY char(3))

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT RATE 
FROM USERCONFIG.dbo.curr 
WHERE CODE = @CCY;
';

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@CCY char(3)',
  @CCY = @CCY;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Dynamic SQL at all here, the reason you are getting the error is because you are. As you have confirmed that the statement you have is literally all you have (there isn't a hidden requirement) just use your non-dynamic statement in your procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST] (@CCY char(3)) AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT RATE 
    FROM USERCONFIG.dbo.curr 
    WHERE CODE = @CCY;
    
END;
```